# Spring data with mongodb version

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Can I use spring-data-mongodb version 1.8.4 (current at this moment) with mongodb 3.2? or this can show some probems?

tks

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data MongoDB generally works with the latest MongoDB Java Driver and server version.

Though, please be aware of the fact, that spring-data-mongodb still relies on the `DBObject` codec. **Not** the the `Document` codec introduced in 3.0. This means also that any registered manually `Codec` will not be applied.

Other changes can be found in the MongoDB 3 section of the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-3).